# "Обход" повторного запроса на сервер

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемые посетители.

Есть веб-приложение, которое используется в нуждах предприятия, по-сути - формирует базу клиентов по сегментам.

Сразу хочу сказать, что все функции приложения работают, проблем нет. Суть обращения - нужна подсказка возможно ли такое + в какую сторону копать.

*Что есть:*

- основная страница (пользователь формирует требования);
- 3 php-файла для обработки разных ajax-запросов;
- 1 js файл для сбора данных из основной страницы и отправки одному из 3-х обработчиков.

***В чем суть вопроса:*** как мне сделать так, чтобы база сформированная на 1-ом этапе выгружалась на 2-ом, так как каждый раз происходит расчет показателей - это занимает определенное время (SQL-запрос очень сложный, оптимизирован, путем правильной конструкции БД + самого запроса).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не нужно делать. Повторный запрос с теми же фильтрами в mysql вернет данные мгновенно, из кэша.

Comment: Используйте кеширование результатов запроса. Например, с использованием memcached.

Comment: @Ипатьев, подскажите, пожалуйста, а если в фильтрах было что-то изменено, к примеру в сегментации изменили возраст, вместо от 18 до 50, поставили от 18 до 55, результирующий набор данных будет другим, соответственно и запрос будет другой же, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @kstkt разумеется другой. странно слышать такой вопрос от человека, у которого "запрос оптимизирован, путем правильной конструкции БД + самого запроса"

Comment: Почему бы не сделать выбор куда будет нужна выгрузка еще на экране фильтров и тогда сразу подготавливать файл, только не отдавать его на клиента а держать где нибудь в /tmp некоторое время для последующей скачки. Или кешировать в чем то еще

Comment: @Mike, этот вариант был первым, но потом решили, что перед тем, как отправить на стороннее API / выгружать в xls необходимо посмотреть сколько таких клиентов, "стоит ли игра свеч". Причем это не всегда файл :)

Comment: так вот вы их посчитаете а готовые данные одновременно сохраните, если набор данных не понадобился по таймауту его удалите. И да, может действительно удобно было бы использовать кеш запросов MySQL, но к сожалению `select count()` и `select *` это разные запросы. так что данные оба раза придется вытянуть на клиента. Ну и кеш бесполезен если хотя бы по одной из используемых таблиц идут частые изменения, так как он сбрасывается при любом обновлении любой таблицы из запроса

Answer (score -1):

Используйте [memcached](http://php.net/manual/ru/memcache.examples-overview.php) при этом ключ формируйте из ваших параметров. Например; md5(serialize($arQueryParams)). Не забывайте В случае измения данных сбрасывать этот кеш.

Comment: а теперь надо подумать, каким боком здесь мемкеш, при rps порядка 0.001